# Capturing optional parameter in ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

I want to catch a mandatory and an optional parameter.

lets say I have a string

```
"X or Y"
```

and "or Y" is optional.

I can do

```
scan /(.*) (or (.*))?/
```

and receive an array with size 3 that includes also the result for the optional catch.

How can I write the scan to receive an array for only the 2 X and Y possibillities?

Thank You

Comment: You can try making the outer group optional - `/(.*) (?:or (.*))?/`

Comment: works great! can you explain?

Comment: `(?:...)` creates a non-capturing groups, which will not add to the total group counts. So, you will not get the content inside it as separate group.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make the outer group of the 2nd part as `non-capturing` group:

```
/(.*) (?:or (.*))?/
```

Now you have only two capturing groups in your regex:

- One capturing the `X` part.
- Another capturing the `Y` part.

So, you will receive an array with these two groups only. And hence you won't get the `or` part.

Answer (score 0):

I needed same answer for this scenario, I googled a lot to get better solution, after playing with logic finally I got success. And it is working perfectly fine in every scenario. Whether URL have one parameter or two. Even we can expand it in n parameters. Very easy to do.

My problem statement was, I had two URLs with small difference.

1st URL ). https://thumbor-cdn1.abc.com/unsafe/700x0/filters:quality(90)/https://s3.amazonaws.com/abc/app_photos/images/1528/original/cover_daily-1.jpg

2nd URL ). https://thumbor-cdn1.abc.com/unsafe/600x0/https://s3.amazonaws.com/abc/users/images/000/263/588/blurred_preview/263588-profile-image-HYU0HBxA5c.jpg

You can see that 1st URL have `700x0/filters:quality(90)` and 2nd URL have only one parameter `600x0`

**And regex is** - `(http|https):\/\/thumbor-cdn1.abc.com\/unsafe\/((.*?)|\/(.*?))\/(http|https):\/\/s3.amazonaws.com\/(abc|xyz)`

**Above url are used for example purpose, for your case you can use valid url.**
Thank you!